# Magento 1.7.0.0 Paypal IPN Returning 200 Response Code

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, ce-1.7.0.0

i'm trying to get paypal standard with the auto return back to my website setup however my orders are stuck at pending payment. When I check in the IPN history i'm getting a 200 response. Does anyone have any help they can offer in debugging this? I have logs turned on but nothing regarding IPN comes into the var folder, only a file called:

payment_paypal_standard.log

That looks like this:

```
        [return] => http://www.mywebsite.com/paypal/standard/success/
        [cancel_return] => http://www.mywebsite.com/paypal/standard/cancel/
        [notify_url] => http://www.mywebsite.com/paypal/ipn/
```

I have read a few forums saying they have further logging specifically around IPN. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also when I test the IPN url from paypal developer it goes through fine, no errors.

Comment: have you tried this tutorial on debugging IPN? http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/debugging-paypal-ipn-in-magento/